# Facebook API, Getting name of friend by his ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I wrote an FQL query to get names of friends who tagged me -

This is the FQL query which gives me the list of the friends ID's(It's Works):

**SELECT owner FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me())**

Now i want to get their names by querying with this :

**SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT owner FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me()))**

But i don't get the full list of the names, and it's stops and gives this error - **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"**

Answer (score 0):

Your query may be failing because some of the `owner` ids returned by your inner query don't belong to users. Try it with the `profile` table instead:

```
SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT owner FROM photo WHERE object_id IN 
    (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me()))
```

Comment: First thanks for ur quick replay, your idea was good, i don't get any error now - BUT, i still don't get the names of all the ID's from the original list, for example without the "SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id IN" i get 143 ID's and after i add the "SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id IN" i get in fact 36 names, buy i think i know why - perhaps if a friend tagged me couple of times in couple of photos it's only count it ones ?

Comment: Quite possible. You would need a multiquery to get this information via FQL and reassemble these two arrays. It's much easier to get this via the Graph API using `/me/photos?fields=id,from`